# Querying multiple meta_keys in Wordpress SQL query

Tags: php, database, wpdb, sql

Here's my Query... I'm looking to narrow this query down to users of one specific role ("meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' AND meta_value = 'employee'")...how do I add that additional conditional to this string?

```
$get_users = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->users
WHERE ID = ANY (
SELECT user_id FROM $wpdb->usermeta
WHERE meta_key = '$meta_key'
AND meta_value LIKE '%$search%'
) ORDER BY user_nicename ASC LIMIT 10000";
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Any reason why you don't can use [WP_User_Query with Custom Field Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) for this?

Comment: I want to be able to search a partial match. For example:
If I'm searching a username and I know what it begins with but not what it ends with I can search for part of it and get results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress Provides a native functions to query these kind of things very easily like [WP_User_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query)

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'     => $meta_key1,
            'value'   => $search1,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => $meta_key2,
            'value'   => $search2,
            'compare' => '='
        )
    )
 );
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```

Comment: It doesn't allow me to use partial matches "%$search%" as far as I know...

Comment: @D3XT3R It should allow you to do partial matching. That is what Bainternet is trying to show by the using like. For $search1 parameter you could have something like \'\%ABC\%\' where the backslash is the escape character in php.

Comment: Ahhh @sri and @bainternet! I completely missed that addition. Thank you very much! Awesome!